# ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation

Tags: mysql, database

Not able to create databases. Not even be able to create tables , users also.GETTING ERROR MESSAGES that no privilege to do the task.
Not even know how to login with different user and passwords.Using MySQL 5.6.12.Accessing the mysql databases from the command prompt through 'bin'.
Please post your answers as soon as possible.

Comment: Try this:
 mysql> GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
After executing above code, end it with:

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'' at line 1.......... Plz do something

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'' at line 1.......... Plz do something.I have done the path settings as well.SHOW GRANTS is showing like this :
| Grants for @localhost                |
+--------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost' |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)